# "Председатель Правительства Москвы". Строчные или прописные буквы?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

Как пишутся слова "Председатель Правительства Москвы" - со строчной или прописной буквы?

Answer (score 1):

Ой, настолько путаные и постоянно меняющиеся рекомендации... Чиновники обожают, когда их пишут с заглавной - и издают соответвующие указивки. 
Но по логике вещей с заглавной пишут названия уникальных должностей - Президент, Премьер и т.д. Входит ли в этот список председатель правительства Москвы, я не знаю.
Я бы писал всё-таки со строчной. И председателя, и правительство.